# New top bar confusion - please help navigate

Tags: discussion, support, design, top-bar

This is possibly a design gripe, but I'm sincerely hoping it's merely a case of me being blind and not seeing existing links.

1. I can't find a link to chat on either main or meta site
2. I can't find a link to main site from meta site (There's a link to my main site user from meta site user)

[image]

How do I make those navigational jumps?

Comment: Full Disclosure - I didn't read any details of new top bar on meta.SO aside from hearing about it on one of the SE podcasts. So I'm viewing this functionality as a newbie and not power user.

Comment: As an aside - we (or at least many people) always complain that new users aren't aware of Meta site's existence. Yet, new design HIDES it even more by stashing under Help menu. One would think that goes contrary to the idea of making meta more visible.

Answer (score 12):

OK, after puttering around some more in the bar, I realized that the "Stack Exchange" logo was a menu, and both missing links were under it. Not the height of convenience but a far better situation than not being available at all.

[image]

Comment: Note to visitors: under Meta Stack Exchange Voting Policy, you are obligated to upvoted based on Presence Of Hand-Drawn Circles.

Comment: +1 Was going to downvote, but circles :(

Comment: @Jeff - now I know how CIA Ultra worked

Answer (score 4):

The 'Stack Exchange' in the top left is clickable, this lets you get to the main/meta site.  There's a link to chat waaaaaay at the bottom of the page.

In addition, you can make some customizations on your end to help make the new topbar more palatable.  [This Meta.SO post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar) has some userscripts and userCSS that lets you customize it to your liking.

I'm using a userscript that adds the main/meta and chat links back to the topbar.

Comment: Yah, it was a blonde moment that I didn't tumble on to the "triangle down=>click here!" cue. \*facepalm*

Comment: Care to share the script?

Comment: @Pureferret I made my own, but [this one](http://stackapps.com/questions/4411/stack-exchange-topbar-tools) offers those features.

Comment: @DVK The blue drowns it out.  I didn't realize there _was_ a drop-arrow triangle until reading your comment just now...